# Are there any pre-print servers that let you export/redistribute the article (not as PDF)?

Tags: copyright, arxiv, preprint

For example, if I were able to get an article from arXiv in a format that isn't PDF, such as LaTeX, docx, html, markdown (really anything covered by pandoc, since that's what I'm using).

From what I can tell, arXiv lets you do this if the article is under CC BY or CC BY-SA license. Does anyone know approx what % of articles on arXiv fall under those?

Also, are there any other pre-print servers which would allow this? They can cover any field and don't have to be in English.

Comment: You can download the source of pretty much any paper from the arXiv (except for the few papers that get submitted as PDFs right away, which is only allowed as an exception). Redistribution rights are a different story.

Comment: Should I perhaps repost the question but just sticking to this part "CC BY or CC BY-SA license. Does anyone know approx what % of articles on arXiv fall under those?" to avoid the shopping questions issue. Because that info would be helpful

Comment: Yes, that would make a much better question.

Comment: Note that format adaptations are possibly forbidden under -ND clauses and that pretty much anything on the internet can fall foul of the -NC clause.

Comment: I may be wrong, but my understanding of the -NC clause is that you may share the material so long as the viewers are not paying directly for it (it's put behind a paywall and pay-to-view). Just from i. NonCommercial on this page https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/legalcode